# Is it possible to initiate a connection ending from the web service, instead of the client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap

I have a SOAP WCF web service which forwards some XML message to a TCP port on another machine (via an HttpWebRequest post). The reason we use this web service is that it can be configured easily to make use two way SSL with client and server certificates.
It is working fine except for the part that there is no FIN message sent by my web service to the client as soon as the HttpWebRequest ends (because a FIN was received on that side). The connection between the web service and the client ends only because the client will send a FIN after a timeout (when KeepAlive is true) or immediately after it received the answer (when KeepAlive is false). So the connection ending is always initiated by the client.

Is it possible to let the web service do the ending of the connection (let the web service send the FIN to the client)?

I already tried to use an event handler like this without luck:

```
OperationContext.Current.OperationCompleted += DisconnectClientImmediatelyAfterResponseEventHandler;

private void DisconnectClientImmediatelyAfterResponseEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OperationContext.Current.Channel.Close();
}
```

This is the complete code of my Post action:

```
public Message Post(Message postRequest)
{
      string bodyOfPostRequest = GetBodyContents(postRequest);            

      IHttpWebRequestWrap remoteRequest = CreateHttpWebRequest();
      try
      {
          using (Stream remoteResponseStream = remoteRequest.Post(bodyOfPostRequest, RemoteRequestContentType))
          {
              string responseMessage = StreamToString(remoteResponseStream);                    
              Message reply = CreateReplyMessage(postRequest.Version, postRequest.Headers.Action, responseMessage);

              return reply;
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          _log.Fatal("The following exception occured.", ex);
          throw;
      }
}
```

The `remoteRequest.Post(...)` is an extension method which does the actual post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was not so hard to accomplish this:

In the web.config the aspNetCompatibilityEnabled attribute of the serviceHostingEnvironment must be set to true:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  ...
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Then the connection can be closed immediately after sending the response by doing this:

```
private void DisconnectClientImmediatelyAfterResponseEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
}
```